# INTERNAL ERROR :Failed assertion [PGE code :90105]

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

While trying to compile sample code with the Pro*C compiler I am getting:

```
c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>proc iname=C:\Users\Selvaganapathy\Desktop
\pro-c\code\sample.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Aug 6 01:00:59 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\preco
mp\admin\pcscfg.cfg


INTERNAL ERROR: Failed assertion [PGE Code=90105]
```

Please help to set up the compiler.

Comment: And what is the code? Can you provide a short example that replicates this behaviour?

Comment: its simple code that connects to oracle and fetches few values from emp table in scott schema .. am just trying to set up my pro* C environment in my laptop . please not it is windows 7 home basic OS

Comment: @ben issue resolved after setting up the path :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have the temporary file

```
C:\Users\Selvaganapathy\Desktop\pro-c\code\sample.c
```

If it exists, retry after deleting this file or provide write permission to it.